# ShareKit 2.0 crashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sharekit

I am using sharekit 2.0 in my iPhone app. I have installed and followed all instruction on https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit. The application builds fine though there is a warning (not an error) as follows

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ilaagarwal/Downloads/Thomas/puzzle game with friends/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers'
```

I have made a button and on button press following action happens

```
- (IBAction)OnShareFacebook:(id)sender {
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:@"message to share"];
NSLog (@"Button Pressed");
}
```

The app crashes once it tries to execute SHKitem line. If I comment that line the action executes fine with out any error. Any clue why it crashes on using SHKItem and how I can fix it.

Comment: If you provide us with the actual crash message, it would help in figuring out your problem.

Comment: Are you sure SHKItem has a class method "text" that creates an instance of SHKItem for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In configuration file for ShareKit I had added the keys in DefaultSHKConfigurator.m but it does not work. I had to do exactly as mentioned in the link https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Configuration and then the application was not crashing so the problem solved.

Comment: This should really be part of the question, not an answer.  You can edit your question by clicking the `edit` link below the tags.

Comment: @JeremyP sorry was not explaining clearly , this was the solution to the problem i was facing